# springboot2 +webflux + websocket

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring boot 2 with Webflux on JDK 11. I wrote the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketMapping(final MyWebSocketHandler server) {
        final Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/echo", server);

        final SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
        return mapping;
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```

And the following `WebSocketHandler` method:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    return webSocketSession.send(webSocketSession.receive().
            map(msg -> webSocketSession
                    .textMessage("response：jack ->" + msg.getPayloadAsText())));
}
```

Now, I can receive whatever I send, like:

client send:4545

client receive :response：jack ->4545

I want to know How can I push message to the client when the client is not sending a message to me, I need push messages at any time！

How do I send a custom message any time rather than responding with the same input message?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it in my blog article http://kojotdev.com/2019/08/spring-webflux-websocket-with-vue-js/.

You need to change your `WebSocketHandler` to:

```
private final GreetingsPublisher greetingsPublisher;
private final Flux<String> publisher;

public ReactiveWebSocketHandler(GreetingsPublisher greetingsPublisher) {
    this.greetingsPublisher = greetingsPublisher;
    this.publisher = Flux.create(greetingsPublisher).share();
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    final Flux<WebSocketMessage> message = publisher
            .map(greetings -> webSocketSession.textMessage(greetings));

    return webSocketSession.send(message);
}
```

And add `GreetingPublisher`

```
@Component
public class GreetingsPublisher implements Consumer<FluxSink<String>> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingsPublisher.class);

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public boolean push(String greeting) {
        return queue.offer(greeting);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(FluxSink<String> sink) {
        this.executor.execute(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Try.of(() -> {
                    final String greeting = queue.take();
                    return sink.next(greeting);
                })
                        .onFailure(ex -> log.error("Could not take greeting from queue", ex));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is a bean so wherever you inject it and call the push method, it is going to send the message with WebSocket. For example:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingsController {

    private final GreetingsPublisher greetingsPublisher;

    public GreetingsController(GreetingsPublisher greetingsPublisher) {
        this.greetingsPublisher = greetingsPublisher;
    }

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> pushMessage() {
        return route(GET("/push"),
                request -> {
                    greetingsPublisher.push("Send a new message with WebSocket");
                    return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromObject("websocket message sent"));
                });
    }
}
```

Connect with WebSocket first and open the browser on localhost:8080/push. The message should be sent.

Note that it seems to be a bug with Spring Boot 2.1.7 and I mentioned about it in my blog post.